# Windows Jenkins "Windows Batch Command" vs Command Prompt

Tags: python, batch-file, jenkins, ssh, command-line-tool

We are using jenkins to run a python script through command prompt. The command is like `C:\Program Files\...\someapp.bat test.py`. The `someapp.bat` is a customized python and it has a library called `arcpy`. The `test.py` file includes a statement `import arcpy`.

This command works fine on command prompt on the machine. However, when running through Jenkins, it complains `arcpy` does not exist. Then I used ssh to access the machine and ran the same command. It has the same error. Then I compared the `path` in the two command prompts (on machine and ssh), the environments has only one difference which is the `Windows`. One under user folder and the other under system. But it does not seem to be a dependency of the python bat.

So, in general, what's difference between a remote command line window and a local command line window if **logged in as the same user**? Any clue is helpful!

Comment: There is no difference.  Did you install `arcpy` in your Jenkins instance?  Is Jenkins using a different version of Python?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes arcpy is installed on Jenkins instance. As claimed in the question, there is no issue using it on a local command line prompt.